# Why linux route config failed with two NIC in redundancy (Primary/secondary)?

Tags: linux, networking, configuration

I've two nic (eth0/eth1) sending data to a router.
Only one is sending data at a time. I also need a static conf that doesn't change regarding if the NIC are up/down.

If I down eth0, I expect eth1 to make the job.
But destroying eth0 destroy also my default route to the router. So I'm done.
Adding 2 default route seem to work by hand, but I don't want this solution.

So I've tried to add "full" route for eth0 and eth1?
By hand it work but I failed to add them in route-eth0 and route-eth1.

```
$cat route-eth0
178.12.34.240 via 10.0.10.1 dev eth0

$cat route-eth1
178.12.34.240 via 10.0.10.1 dev eth1

$service network restart
...
Bringing up interface eth1:
Determining IP information for eth1... done.
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
...

$route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
178.12.34.240   10.00.10.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
...
```

As you can see route for eth1 failed to be applied. For sure because of the File exist error.

**Question:**

What is the conf to set to always have correct route whatever the NIC are up or down.

Or another best practice ? What about VIP?

Comment: Sorry but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for help with network configurations, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  
***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: You _should_ just add a second default route with a larger metric. That is a floating static route, and it is dormant until the primary interface is down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ron metric is the answer. But I did it on a static route.

It seems having several default route should be banned.

```
$cat route-eth0
178.12.34.240 via 10.0.10.1 metric 1 dev eth0

$cat route-eth1
178.12.34.240 via 10.0.10.1 metric 2 dev eth1
```

Comment: A static default route is just a static route, albeit with a larger network. Why should that be banned?

Comment: Maybe you are right. Some "so called" expert tell me that Linux IP stack (centos) doesn't managed very well 2 NICs on the same VLAN. They argue that a request can be sent on a NIC and the answer can be received on the another one. No proof of such behaviour obviously.